# Multiple Preferences for single app using AppCompatPreferenceActivity?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences

I'm making an app that will have a list with multiple devices (let's say that each device is just an IP address string) that the user saved. For each device I need to save some preferences, such as device name that the user sets, if the device is enabled by the user, etc.

I was able to create a `SettingsActivity` and Android Studio made this extremely easy. The problem is that these settings are global, for the whole app. Is there a way to have separate settings for each one of the user's saved devices? Or I'll have to with the `SharedPreferences` for each device? It's just that the `SettingsActivity` is so convenient and everything just works.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use SharedPreferences directly to store the data structures. The scaffolded SettingsActivity is only designed for app global settings.

I would almost be inclined to say you should be using a database, since it sounds like your app allows users to save and read a potentially large amount of data - not something SharedPreferences was designed for.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say "large data" as the user will have 4-5 devices at max and each device has 4 settings. Should I still consider using shared preferences or should I move to a database?

Comment: I would suggest a database, since the structure of the data doesn't seem to fit the ideal use case of SharedPreferences - storing scalar preference settings.